# Serialize a custom object inside json object

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, serialization

I am using a third party python library, which returns some data in lists and dictionaries inside them (JSON format). For example, here's a sample entry:

```
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 80, 'c': 42, 'd': [{'r': 0, 's': '1', 'u': 5}], 'id': 10, 'k': 60, 'v': 0, 'm': 
{'ty': 'djp', 'nr': '10', 'bc': Adder('179'), 'in': 3}}, {'a': 1, 'b': 70, 'c': 42, 'd': [{'r': 0, 's': 
'1', 'u': 5}], 'y': 10, 'k': 60, 'v': 0, 'm': {'ty': 'djp', 'dx': '10', 'tx': Adder('179'), 'in': 3}}]
```

My problem is with 'Adder' class which is an object. Everything else are just strings.

So, when I do:

```
json.dumps(data)
```

It causes an error message:

> Adder('179') is not JSON serializable.

I don't care about serializing this Adder class, so I would somehow like to just make it a string e.g. "Adder(179)" if possible. Is it possible to make the dumps function work? Class *Adder* is not my own, maybe I can make it serialized or tell it what to do with it by editing the source or something? Any simple way would be fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify a [custom encoder class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder):

```
class RobustEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        try:
            return super(RobustEncoder, self).default(o)
        except TypeError:
            return str(o)    

json.dumps(data, cls=RobustEncoder)
```

The keyword argument `cls` is documented in the docs of [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump).

Comment: Assuming OP has `__str__` or `__repr__` defined in the `Adder` class.

Comment: Since the OP states *"I don't care about serializing this Adder class, so I would somehow like to just make it a string"* and `__str__` is inherited from `object`, this should be fairly robust for any type.

Comment: Thats true, but he did state *"I would somehow like to just make it a string e.g. "Adder(179)" if possible"*. So you would have to add `__str__`, otherwise this will print the inherited `object`  `__str__` representation instead. Not really an issue because the OP can make their own pretty easily, and this approach solves the bulk of the problem. +1 from me :)

Comment: @RoadRunner True, that step to control the string representation is quite small. This answer jsut demonstrates the principle. I think it is quite clear how to adopt the encoder class to basically do anything you want with the object `o` that is to be serialized.